# Sampling Large Data Files

Tags: editor, text-editor, flat-file

I currently work in the position of Data Warehouse programmer and as such have to put numerous flat files through ETL process. Of course prior to loading the file I have to be aware of its content, the problem is that majority of the files are > 1 GB large and I can not open them using my dear old friend "notepad". Kidding. I usually use VIM or Notepad++ but it still takes a while to open the file. Could I perform a "partial" read of the file using VIM or some other editor?

P.S. I know that I could write a 10 liner script to "data sample" the file, but it would be simpler to convince team members to use a feature of an editor than a script that I wrote.

Thank you for any insight you might have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick with using vim, you could have a look at the [LargeFile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) script.

Alternatively, I've always found that [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) opens large files extremely quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You said you had VIM, that makes me wonder if you have a unix environment as well?

If you like, you can pipe the input through unix utility `top` and display the raw imput on your screen. Like this:

**EDIT**: (thanks Honk)

`terminal$> head -N 15 file.csv`

(Where that 15 indicates you want to see 15 lines only).

Comment: Not sure if `top` is special in mainframe Unixes, but on Linux you would pipe into `head -n 15`.

Comment: Or you would even avoid the unnecessary `cat` with `head -n 15 file.csv`. This should be orders of magnitude faster, too.

Comment: Thanks, but I am just a big fan of UNIX, our environment is built on MS stack.

Comment: @a_person - being a fan of UNIX but on Microsoft, you might like CYGWIN! This is an off-the-topic suggestion, though. : )

Comment: I definitely appreciate this suggestion and actually have it installed :).

Comment: @a_person +1 for being a CYGWIN fan as well n_n

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure there are loads of similar questions, but hey, [Textpad](http://www.textpad.com/) is a good choice for this.

Comment: Verified & Confirmed. Textpad opened a 1.3 GB file flawlessly in 6 seconds for me (although saving it took much, much longer).

Comment: TextPad ended up being waaay too slow when tasked with opening the file taking quite a bit longer than Notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

use the head command.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'less' on solaris ... use the same through cygwin on windows. On mainframes this problem doesn't appear, ISPF editor handles it pretty well.

Comment: CYGWIN also handles `less` , and `top`

Answer (score 0):

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/large_file_handling.html) claims to handle files over 4GB...